# appwrite_auth_kit how to use auth via phone method

Tags: flutter, appwrite

i use appwrite_auth_kit package in my flutter project.
Can you briefly explain how to use createPhoneSession? More precisely, how to get a token and then insert it into updatePhoneSession? After all, the createPhoneSession method returns only true or false.